# Не работает go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint

Tags: git, get, golang

Не уверен что дело в путях. Они у меня такие:

```
GOROOT C:\Go\
GOPATH C:\Gowork\ 
Path C:\Go\bin
```

Собственно не работает. Выполняю:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/lint/golint
```

И выдается ошибка:

> package [путь и имя пакета gcimporter15]: [путь к папке tools] exists but [путь к папке tools.git] **does not - stale checkout?**

Но другие пакеты у меня в каталог `C:\Gowork\src\` установились.

1. В чем же может быть проблема?
2. А вообще нужно ли скачивать и устанавливать git для работы `go get`?

Comment: git нужен если ты делаешь go get из git-репозитория (например с гитхаба), так же нужен mercurial и bazaar, если будешь брать проекты из соответсвующих репозиториев

Answer (score 3):

```
А вообще нужно ли скачивать и устанавливать git для работы программы go get?
```

Да, нужно. Без него go get не работает.